# Ethernet Connected But No Internet

Tags: dns, ethernet, yocto

I am trying this on Intel Galileo Gen 2 which runs `Yocto` Linux and I am unable to connect to Internet using Ethernet. I have WiFi card but that doesn't connect as well. I have tried following commands and their outputs are as below

`ifconfig -a`

Output:

```
enp0s20f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:4F:EE:01:9E:CA
          inet addr:192.168.0.110  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9a4f:eeff:fe01:9eca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2731 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:599 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:276624 (270.1 KiB)  TX bytes:84524 (82.5 KiB)
          Interrupt:51 Base address:0x4000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5730 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5730 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:503288 (491.4 KiB)  TX bytes:503288 (491.4 KiB)

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:85:00:01:8A:D3
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

`route -n`

Output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s20f6
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s20f6
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp0s20f6
```

The interfaces look like:

`vi /etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto enp0s20f6
iface enp0s20f6 inet static
  address 10.254.253.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
     wireless_mode managed
     wireless_essid any
     wpa-driver wext
     wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

On trying `connmanctl services` I get,

```
*AR Wired                ethernet_984fee019eca_cable
*A  wifinw           wifi_448500018ad3_646c696e6b2d32333238_managed_psk
```

So `ping www.google.com` fails with `bad address`. I tried `ping 8.8.8.8` and it gives response. As per @frarugi87 its a DNS issue, but I am not sure how to fix this.

The `/etc/resolv.conf` has following nameservers

```
# Generated by Connection Manager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver ::1
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this adding OpenDNS servers to my `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

`vi /etc/resolv.conf`

and the file looks like

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

After this, ping to google.com works.